# How to install any php extension in AWS Amazon Linux AMI?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Today I was stuck at the point where I was trying to install php-tidy to AWS Ami Linux.

It took 4 hours to install me a right version of extension to AWS EC2. So it's really painful for everyone if it takes a long time to install just a simple extension. So I finally found few command lines to install any supported aws php extension to working states.

Check below answer

Answer (score 17):

First Login to Putty | SSH

Use `sudo yum` command in case it ask for super admin permission.

1. `yum list | grep tidy` : as I was trying to install tidy extension so I searched for tidy. you can change it to any extension name. Below will be output for above command

`php-tidy.x86_64                      5.3.29-1.8.amzn1              amzn-main
php54-tidy.x86_64                    5.4.45-1.75.amzn1             amzn-main
php55-tidy.x86_64                    5.5.38-2.119.amzn1            amzn-main
php56-tidy.x86_64                    5.6.40-1.142.amzn1            amzn-updates
php70-tidy.x86_64                    7.0.33-1.32.amzn1             amzn-updates
php71-tidy.x86_64                    7.1.29-1.39.amzn1             amzn-updates
php73-tidy.x86_64                    7.3.5-1.15.amzn1              amzn-updates
tidy.x86_64                          0.99.0-19.20070615.1.4.amzn1  amzn-main
tidyp.x86_64                         1.02-9.2.amzn1                amzn-main`

2. `sudo yum list installed | grep php` : This command will help us to know which version we need to install from php56, php70, php72, Output will be below:

`php7-pear.noarch                     1:1.10.7-3.28.amzn1           @amzn-updates
php72.x86_64                         7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-bcmath.x86_64                  7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-cli.x86_64                     7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-common.x86_64                  7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-devel.x86_64                   7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-gd.x86_64                      7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-intl.x86_64                    7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-json.x86_64                    7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-mbstring.x86_64                7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-mysqlnd.x86_64                 7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-odbc.x86_64                    7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-opcache.x86_64                 7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-pdo.x86_64                     7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-pecl-apcu.x86_64               5.1.8-2.7.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php72-pecl-igbinary.x86_64           1.2.2-0.1.20151217git2b7c703.8.amzn1
php72-pecl-imagick.x86_64            3.4.3-1.8.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php72-pecl-mcrypt.x86_64             1.0.1-3.5.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php72-pecl-memcache.x86_64           3.0.9-0.4.20160311git4991c2f.11.amzn1
php72-pecl-memcached.x86_64          3.0.4-1.6.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php72-pecl-oauth.x86_64              2.0.2-1.5.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php72-pecl-ssh2.x86_64               1.0-5.19.amzn1                @amzn-updates
php72-pecl-uuid.x86_64               1.0.4-7.3.amzn1               @amzn-updates
php72-pgsql.x86_64                   7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-process.x86_64                 7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-soap.x86_64                    7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-tidy.x86_64                    7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-xml.x86_64                     7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates
php72-xmlrpc.x86_64                  7.2.18-1.13.amzn1             @amzn-updates`

It clearly says we need php72-extenstionname

3. `sudo yum install php72-tidy.x86_64` : this is last command to install this particular extension.

Hope I have saved your 3-4 hours to find out solution.

Thanks

Comment: You bet,  you did save me a few hours, Thanks