# How to install/use AWS:ElastiCache Redis session for Yii2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

The question is simple,

How to install/use AWS:ElastiCache Redis session for Yii2?

Self answered. Please read below

Answer (score 0):

### Steps to Install and Enable Redis

- [Self Managed] Install Redis-Server in your webserver, using [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-redis-server-as-a-session-handler-for-php-on-ubuntu-14-04) link or for [AWS EC2](https://shawn-shi.medium.com/how-to-install-redis-on-ec2-server-for-fast-in-memory-database-f30c3ef8c35e)
- [AWS ElastiCache] AWS ElastiCache for Redis: How to Use the [AWS Redis Service](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/aws-cvo-blg-aws-elasticache-for-redis-how-to-use-the-aws-redis-service)
- Install PHP Redis extension. [AWS Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203023/how-to-install-any-php-extension-in-aws-amazon-linux-ami/60203024#60203024)
- Apply session.save_path = `Endpoint ElastiCache` & session.save_handler = `redis` in php.ini
- Restart the services
- Confirm the change in php.ini by `phpinfo();`
- Apply Redis session in Yii2 Component as [said here](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-redis/doc/api/2.0/yii-redis-session)

### Make sure you follow this.

- Use the same security group for EC2 and ElastiCache
- Add Redis Port 6379 in AWS Security Group as 0.0.0.0
- While configuration In Yii2, main.php add ElastiCache endpoint as host
- These steps for the session only, so modify Yii2 main component if you want to use Redis as active data or to cache